# Python Pandas: How to Remove Unwanted Leading and Trialing Strings in Column Value

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my original data frame:

```
+------------+
|        name|
+------------+
|     mr mike|
+------------+
|        john|
+------------+
|     andy mr|
+------------+
|  andy mr ho|
+------------+
```

I'd like to remove all leading and trailing "mr" strings. And, the "mr" should be kept if it's in not the trailing or leading characters of the column value. Below is the expected data frame:

```
+------------+
|        name|
+------------+
|        mike|
+------------+
|        john|
+------------+
|        andy|
+------------+
|  andy mr ho|
+------------+
```

I have tried below but it will remove all the "mr" strings.

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('mr', '')
```

Please suggest and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following;

```
df['name1'] =df.name.str.replace('^mr|mr$','', regex=True)



        name       name1
0     mr mike        mike
1        john        john
2     andy mr       andy 
3  andy mr ho  andy mr ho
```